# Regexp to match function calls

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regexp to match calls of autoloaded Vimscript functions.  Autoloaded function names look like:

```
foo#bar()
foo#bar#baz()
```

They contrast with script-local calls which look like:

```
s:foo()
```

However I don't want to match function definitions, which look like:

```
function foo#bar()
function foo#bar#baz()
```

I started with a regexp to match function names:

```
(\w+(?:#\w+)+)\(
```

I.e. match `foo#bar(` or `foo#bar#baz(` and capture everything except the opening bracket.

Then I added a negative lookbehind to exclude function names preceded by `function`.

```
(?<!function )(\w+(?:#\w+)+)\(
```

However given `function foo#bar()` it matched `oo#bar(`.

So I added a word boundary:

```
(?<!function )\b(\w+(?:#\w+)+)\(
```

Now it correctly doesn't match `function foo#bar()` at all.

However given `function foo#bar#baz()` it matches `bar#baz(`.  I can see why: the `#` after `foo` is a word boundary.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get around this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your negative lookbehind also add `#` to make sure you don't match from position just after `#`

```
(?<!\bfunction |#)(\b\w+(?:#\w+)+)
```

Also note use of word boundaries before `function` and before `\w+` to avoid false matches.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVSIqQ/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?!function)\w+(?:#\w+)+(?=\()
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQ7Trj/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?!function)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current position is not immediately followed by `function`
- `\w+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word-character(letters, digits and underscore)
- `(?:#\w+)+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a `#` followed by 1+ word characters
- `(?=\()` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is followed by `(`

Comment: Thank you!  However the `^` anchor means it incorrectly doesn't match `call foo#bar#baz()` and without that anchor it incorrectly matches `function foo#bar#baz()`.

Comment: I like the final positive lookahead though :)